# Moving child element out of parent element

Tags: html, css

I have a custom PHP CMS which uses templates. I have a layout.tpl in which I set the overall look of the site including a class called boxmain which is the central content of the layout. In that, I have defined my style.css file, which contains the boxmain class.

```
.boxmain { 
    background-color:#F5F5F5; 
    width:1025px;
    height:auto; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    font-size:11px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Above it, I have a class for an image banner. This also contains a margin to create a space between the content and the banner.

```
div#banner {
    background: url("../images/banners/banner1.jpg")  repeat scroll center center rgb(0, 0, 0);
    width: 100%;
    height: 270px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom: 25px; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 2px 15px 2px ;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px 2px ;
}
```

What I want to do, is to be able to remove all of the padding and margins on the banner and on the boxmain without having to modify the stylesheet, but instead including it in the template. For some reason, it doesn't work when I do this in the template, it just breaks Cufon.

```
<style type="text/css">
div.boxmain { margin: 0; padding; 0; }
div#banner { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
</style>
```

I was therefore thinking, maybe position the child elements (basically all of the content from the template) out of the parent element (boxmain defined in layout.tpl) and this would clear the margins and the paddings, but how can I do this and would it work?

The content in the template is basically a few div tags and a few images.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uTZBz/).

```
<style type="text/css">
div.boxmain { margin: 0; padding; 0; }
div#banner { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
</style>

<div id="banner">Banner content</div>
<div class="boxmain">Main content</div>
```

Since the inline style easily overrides the main stylesheet, I would say, this is an ordering issue. You probably include the main stylesheet *after* the inline style, which would explain why it is not working.

Moving the inline `<style>` into `boxmain` works too

```
<div id="banner">Banner content</div>
<div class="boxmain">

    <style type="text/css">
    div.boxmain { margin: 0; padding; 0; }
    div#banner { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    </style>

    Main content
</div>
```

So, prefixing `$page_content` with the overriding style should do as well.
See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uTZBz/1/)

Disclaimer: this is tested with Firefox 16 only.

Comment: Right, makes sense actually, but the issue is that boxmain and banner are inside layout.tpl, which sets the layout for all of the pages. So, stylesheet link, `<div id="banner"></div>` followed by `<div class="boxmain"><?php echo $page_content;?></div>` echoing the content in the template I'm looking to change. I get what you're saying, basically the `<style>` is inside boxmain, when it should be outside, but outside means setting it for all of the pages.

Comment: @zzwyb89 I'm not sure, if I really understand. Do you mean the overriding `<style>` is inside `$page_content`? And you want to override the margin for some pages, but not for all?

Comment: Exactly that :) I want to remove the margin for selected pages only.